# Generate HTML report based on R script, stop execution of script when error occurs, generate the report upto and including that error?

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

I am trying to generate a report from an R script using rmarkdown::render(). If there is an error in my script, I would like the script to stop, and I would like to render the report up to that point, including the error. So far, I have this:

**Script 1**

```
rmarkdown::render("Script 2")
```

**Script 2**

```
#+ include = TRUE 
knitr::opts_chunk$set(error = TRUE)
knitr::knit_hooks$set(error = function(x, ...) {
  knit_exit(); x
})
#+ 

stop("this is an error!")

message("this message shouldn't be displayed")

stop("second error")
```

This is what the output looks like:
[image: Output of minimal reproducible example]

As you can see, the script generates the report including all the errors, but what I want it to do is stop executing the script upon encountering the first error, and then generate the html log upto and including that error. In my example, that means that I don't want the message "this message shouldn't be displayed", or anything after, to be displayed. However, using the example script, the message is visible and everything after is visible in the output.

Answer (score 1):

For this `error` hook to take effect, you need to set the chunk option `error = TRUE`, e.g.,

```r
knitr::opts_chunk$set(error = TRUE)
```

---

*Update after question edit (2023-03-08):*

The two errors need to be in separate code chunks, because the `error` hook is executed after a whole code chunk has finished execution. It's not possible to exit knitting after the first error in a code chunk when there is a second error later in the same chunk.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have indeed tried putting error = TRUE.  However, this doesn't solve the issue. With error = TRUE the script prints an error everytime it occurs, but it keeps on running. What I'm looking for specifically, is a solution where the script terminates when an error occurs,, but a log HTML is still generated upto and including the error that terminated the script.

Comment: That's odd. Please provide a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: Thank you, I have edited the original question with an example and updated description of the problem.

Comment: I see. The two errors need to be in separate code chunks, because the `error` hook is executed after a whole code chunk has finished execution. It's not possible to exit knitting after the first error in a code chunk when there is a second error later in the same chunk.